# Gradle define dependcies with api but found dependencies both in api configuration and implementation configuration

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to publish my Android library project's dependencies to a maven repository. So I add below code in the build Gradle file.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bundleRelease
            pom.withXml {
                //Creating additional node for dependencies
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                //Defining configuration names from which dependencies will be taken (debugCompile or releaseCompile and compile)
                def configurationNames = ["releaseCompile", 'compile', 'api', "implementation"]
                configurationNames.each { configurationName ->
                    if (!configurations.names.contains(configurationName)) {
                        return
                    }
                    configurations[configurationName].allDependencies.each {
                        if (it.group != null && it.name != null) {
                            def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                            dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)

                            //If there are any exclusions in dependency
                            if (it.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
                                def exclusionsNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                                it.excludeRules.each { rule ->
                                    def exclusionNode = exclusionsNode.appendNode('exclusion')
                                    exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group)
                                    exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I found my pom file has double dependencies which content is the same. Just like below:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My gradle dependencies with `api`:

```
dependencies {
    api "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gson_version}"
}
```

I add some log in publishing. And I found `api` configuration and `implementation` configuration both have gson library dependency.

I'm so confused. Would someone like to explain why this happened?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this problem.
Because I used `allDependencies` which will get the complete set of dependencies including those contributed by superconfigurations.

```
configurations[configurationName].allDependencies.each {
}
```

`implementation` extends the configuration `api`. So we will get dependencies those contributed by `api` when we get `allDependencies` of `implementation`.

In this situation, I should use `dependencies` which get the set of dependencies directly contained in this configuration (ignoring superconfigurations).

```
configurations[configurationName].dependencies.each {
}
```

More information about configuration extends in [here](https://heapandstack.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/find-the-superconfigurations-for-the-gradle-configuration/).